# How to implement multi model search using sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-solr

There are two models User and Language, having association (has_many :languages). Now I want to search a language name and the search obtained should tell the user id as well. In other words that language belongs to which user.

How to implement the same using sunspot.

Regards,
Karan

Comment: Can you not just refer to the user through the association on the returned language, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, we can achieve by your method but if in case we need to fetch results in a single go using sunspot search only....can't it be possible..? Does sunspot provides this kind of feeature.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what exactly you need , i hope this post can help you a bit  .

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base 

     has_many :languages

     # Searchable block for Sunspot-Solr

     searchable do

       # for facet search
       integer :language_id , :multiple => true , :references => Language do
         languages.collect(&:id).compact if languages.any?
       end

       # for text Search
       text :languages , :boost => 5 do
         languages.map {|language| language.name } if languages.any?
       end

     end

    end
```